# Django form validation errors being duplicated

Tags: python, django, forms, validation

I have the following form in django:

```
class UserEmailRegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    password = forms.PasswordField(max_length=32, label=_('Password'),
                                   validators=[validators.validate_password])
    email = forms.EmailField(label=_('Email'), 
                             validators=[validators.validate_email])
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=35, label=_('First name'), 
                                 validators=[validators.validate_name])
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=35, label=_('Last name'), 
                                validators=[validators.validate_name])
```

Most validators are custom, but `validate_email` is as seen in `django.core.validators`. Also, here's the relevant part of my view:

```
form = UserEmailRegistrationForm(PUT)       
    # Validate incoming data
    if not form.is_valid():
        return HttpResponse(form.errors.as_json(), 
                            content_type='application/json', status=422)
```

All validators are working fine, but I get `Enter a valid email address.` twice in `form.errors` when I pass along an invalid email address. Here's the response I get:

```
{"email": [{"message": "Enter a valid email address.", "code": "invalid"}, {"message": "Enter a valid email address.", "code": "invalid"}]}
```

What could be causing this and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To debug / see what's happening. In your IDE click on EmailField and follow the hierarchy...

1.Your code:

```
email = forms.EmailField(label=_('Email'), 
                         validators=[validators.validate_email])
```

2.EmailField:

```
class EmailField(CharField):
    widget = EmailInput
    default_validators = [validators.validate_email]
```

3.CharField / nothing interesting.

```
class CharField(Field): ...
```

4.`Field.__init__(...)`:

```
...
self.validators = self.default_validators + validators
super(Field, self).__init__()
```

In short, you're using validate_email twice.

Comment: Fixed it! It's a strange behaviour, though. Maybe the parameter should be called something like "extra_validators", it seams more reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

As François intimated, there a *two* identical validators associated with your `email` field. The first is there by default, and then you add a second one by supplying a value for the `validators` keyword argument (`validators=[validators.validate_email]`). This validator list is appended to any default ones. Hence you are seeing 2 validation error messages.

```
$ python manage.py shell
>>> from django import forms
>>> from django.core import validators
>>> email = forms.EmailField(label=_('Email'), validators=[validators.validate_email])
>>> email.validators
[<django.core.validators.EmailValidator object at 0x2bc0190>, <django.core.validators.EmailValidator object at 0x2bc0190>]
```

So you can see above that there are 2 registered validators. When the form is validated both are executed:

```
>>> email.run_validators('abc@abc.com')
>>> email.run_validators('abc')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/mhawke/virtualenvs/django_1.6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 139, in run_validators
    raise ValidationError(errors)
ValidationError: [u'Enter a valid email address.', u'Enter a valid email address.']
```

To fix, simply declare the email field without the validator:

```
>>> email = forms.EmailField(label=_('Email'))
>>> email.validators
[<django.core.validators.EmailValidator object at 0x2bc0190>]
>>> email.run_validators('abc@abc.com')
>>> email.run_validators('abc')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/mhawke/virtualenvs/django_1.6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 139, in run_validators
    raise ValidationError(errors)
ValidationError: [u'Enter a valid email address.']
```